# ¿Usar Require() en el navegador?

Tags: javascript, babeljs, required

Tengo un modulo donde implemento una cola

```
    class Queue {
constructor() {
    this.cola = [];
}

enqueue(element) {

    this.cola.push(element);
}
dequeue() {

    return this.cola.shift();
}
peek() {
    return this.cola[0];
}
size() {
    return this.cola.length;
}
isEmpy() {
    return this.cola.length === 0;
}
print() {
    return this.cola;
}
```

}

```
   export default Queue;
```

Lo importo en mi archivo principal app.js

```
    import Cola from './Cola'
    let cola = new Cola();
```

Luego al usar Babel para transpilar mi codigo
el cual me queda el siguiente

```
    'use strict';

    var _Cola = require('./Cola');

    var _Cola2 = _interopRequireDefault(_Cola);

    function _interopRequireDefault(obj) { return obj && obj.__esModule ? obj : { default: obj }; }

    var cola = new _Cola2.default();
```

*var _Cola2 = _interopRequireDefault(_Cola);* <= esta línea me da error y hasta ahora nose como solucionarlo

Comment: creo que necesitas usar "module bundler" para concantenar todos los ficheros js en un único fichero js. Puedes usar webpack, parcel o vite hay muchos pero estos son los más populares.

Comment: Muchas Gracias !!!! Me olvide de agradecer !